# Adding Pushover integration in Django

Tags: django

I've recently started using Pushover.net, I've done some searching and can't find any examples of it being integrated with a django project.

Since i can't find any examples I've decided it would be fun to try myself. What I'm interested in is how you would suggest I do it. I want the actual pushover part as decoupled a possible, hence doing it asas an app.

What I'm not entirely sure on how to approach is the user authorization. The idea being a user enters their pushover user key and its saved in a user profile model using django's `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` with some functions such as `has_pushover`  but obviously I'd like some security so the user keys aren't stored in plaintext. What do people suggest for this?

Is there some inbuilt django security I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past when I've needed to encrypt Django fields I used the encrypted fields available in [django-fields](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields). You could use one of these on your UserProfile model and define a `has_pushover()` method on the model which basically returns whether the pushover token field is `None` or not.

I'm guessing because you're talking about storing each user's Pushover token you are wanting to build an app for pushing arbitrary notifications to your website's users? This is in contrast to having the website just push notifications to yourself for site events.